# How to escape special characters (e.g., string.whitespace) in log messages?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to log strings with special characters in them. I know python has a `logging` module but for simplicity I've defined the following log function which takes a file handle and the message to be logged:

```
def log(logfp, msg):
    logfp.write(f'{msg}\n')

fp = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
log(fp, 'Hello World!')
log(fp, 'World:\nHello, Bob!')
fp.close()
```

> ### logfile.txt
>
> Hello World!
>   World:
>   Hello, Bob!

What I would like is:

> Hello World!
>   World:\nHello, Bob!

So that each line of the logfile corresponds exactly to a single call to `log()`.

I tried using string.replace(r'\', r'\\') but that did not work:

```
def log(logfp, msg):
    msg = msg.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\')
    logfp.write(f'{msg}\n')
```

I tried [Cid's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073532/5972766) which worked for `\n` but not other whitespace chars:

```
import os
import string

def log(fp, msg):
    msg = msg.replace("\n", "\\n")
    fp.write(f'{msg}\n')

# Replaces \t \n \r \x0b \x0c with a backslash counterpart (not including space chars)
def log2(fp, msg):
    replacement = {ch:f'\\{ch}' for ch in string.whitespace[1:]}
    for ch in string.whitespace[1:]:
        msg = msg.replace(ch, replacement[ch])
    fp.write(f'{msg}\n')

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mtran\Desktop') # Change working directory
logfp = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
log(logfp, 'Hello World!')
log(logfp, 'World:\nHello, Bob!')
log2(logfp, 'World:\t\n\r\x0b\x0cHello, Everyone!')
logfp.close()
```

> ### logfile.txt
>
> Hello World!
>   World:\nHello, Bob!
>   World:\   \
>   \
>   \Hello, Everyone!

Comment: it's simple  use \\n instead of \n

Comment: @aman5319 I tried using `string.replace` to replace backslashes with two backslashes but this does not replace special characters with their escaped counterparts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the string `"\n"`, you can't directly replace `\` by `\\` because `\n` is **one** character. You see it composed with `\` and `n` but it's interpreted as one character.

You'd rather replace `\n` by `\\n` :

```
def log(msg):
    msg = msg.replace("\n", "\\n")
    print(msg)

log('Hello World!')
log('World:\nHello, Bob!')
```

This outputs

```
Hello World!
World:\nHello, Bob!
```

Comment: Updated my question with your suggestion. Replacement does not work for other whitespace chars.

Comment: Well, you can apply the same again and again with others whitespaces